# Install extension in Yii2

Tags: npm, yii2, composer-php, bower, fabricjs

Hi can someone show me steps how can I install fabric.js in yii2 project? This is Fabric.js: [link to github](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/)

There I can see that I can install fabric.js only by bower or npm. I don know that i have bower on start in Yii2 procejct or I should I install this bower. Now I only used composer install and update. And I dont know how to install this in my project. Maybe anyone can show me easiest way to install this by composer only or other easy way? I tried to write command :

> bower install fabric

but i have error:

> bash: bower: command not found

Comment: Did you search the web for Bower? It should be pretty easy to find, and I'm sure its installation is documented. Same with NPM.

Comment: I tried to install bower by "bower-asset/jquery": "*" in required in composer.json but i have info "Nothing to install or update" when I use composer update. So I dont know that i have installe bower or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have got Composer asset plugin installed. If not run console command:

```
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:^1.2.0"
```

All you have to do now is to add in `require` section of composer.json

```
"bower-asset/fabric": "*"
```

and run `composer update` command in console (in the project folder).

Comment: this wa i have eror: Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package bower-asset/fabric.js could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Comment: "bower-asset/fabric.js": "1.6.4" run the same error

Comment: still the same error:  Problem 1
    - The requested package bower-asset/fabric could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Comment: "bower-asset/fabric" works for sure, I've tested it. Probably you don't have asset plugin after all. I updated my answer again.

Comment: Thanks man You are great! :) Now I must  "create a GitHub OAuth token to go over the API rate limit" You hear about this token?

Comment: Follow the step-by-step instruction at http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html Everything is explained there,

Comment: it is possible to do the same thing for npm?

Comment: @ValRob Yes, as long as package name in NPM is the same.

Comment: So, in the case of [fabric](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fabric) where you run `$ bower install fabric` and specify in the `composer.json` with `"bower-asset/fabric": "*"` here, i should try set in the `composer.json` `"npm-assets/fabric": "*"` right? @Bizley